# Android Tone Generator works on S3; but not on S4

Tags: android

I have these code:

```
          int sampleRate = 44100;
          int freqOfTone = 1000;
          AudioTrack track;
          short samples[] = new short[sampleRate];
          track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                   sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                       AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,samples.length*Short.SIZE/Byte.SIZE,
                                                AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
          double angle = 0;
          double increment = (2 * Math.PI * freqOfTone / sampleRate);
          for (int i = 0; i < samples.length-1; i++) {
                    samples[i] =   (short) (Math.sin(angle) * Short.MAX_VALUE);
                    angle += increment;
          }                

          track.write(samples, 0, samples.length);  

          track.play();
```

it supposes to generate a 1 second 1k sinus beep.
one could hear the beep on S3; but it does not work on S4.
could anybody tell how to make this beep on S4?

Comment: "Does not work" is not helpful. Please provide more information, such as, but not limited to: Do you get any messages in the logcat? Have you tried other values? Is your phone's volume up? Do other apps play sound? Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: i have tried everything and it's not working on S4. it works on S3 as expected: beep for 1 second.

Comment: it's just white noise on S4. i tried two S4 after reboot and everything. it's just white nose on S4

Comment: I suspect that this is some kind of hardware issue with the Galaxy S4 but I am yet to see any confirmation from official sources. I have observed the same behaviour of only playing white noise instead of the audio data.